# Make a container stretch to remaining height in a Flutter ListView Item

Tags: flutter

How can I adjust the code to make the container inside the ListViewItem take up the remaining available height, similar to the connecting lines in a Twitter thread? Here's my current implementation:

```
Widget _buildListViewItem(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                  child: CircledLetterAvatar(
                    text: "T",
                    size: 40,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      width: 2,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text("Full Name"),
                  Text(
                    "In publishing and graphic design, "
                    "Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate "
                    "the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. "
                    "Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available",
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that the container inside the ListViewItem is not taking up the remaining height available. I want it to stretch vertically to the same height as the right column (the one with "Full Name" and the paragraph).

Below is the expected result:

[image]

Any ideas on this will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.0),
              child: VerticalDivider(
                color: Colors.blue,
                thickness: 3,
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    IntrinsicHeight(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: ClipOval(
                          child: Material(
                            elevation: 4,
                            color: Colors.blue, // Button color
                            child: Container(
                              width: 40,
                              height: 40,
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  "T",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text("Full Name"),
                            Text(
                              "In publishing and graphic design, "
                              "Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate "
                              "the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. "
                              "Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available",
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        )
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Wrap the whole **'Row'** widget inside an **'Expanded'** widget. This will ensure the **'Row'** widget takes up all the available vertical space within the column. Then you can you **'Expanded'** widgets inside the **'Row'** to achieve your desired layout.

Code:

```
Widget _buildListViewItem(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      Expanded( // Wrap the Row inside Expanded
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                    child: CircledLetterAvatar(
                      text: "T",
                      size: 40,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded( // Use Expanded to make the container take remaining height
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 2,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded( // Use Expanded to make the right column take remaining width
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text("Full Name"),
                    Text(
                      "In publishing and graphic design, "
                      "Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate "
                      "the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. "
                      "Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available",
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work